# Handling data from Dead Letter Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have the following pipeline in place to move events:-

Service -> SNS -> AWS Lambda -> Dynamo Db.

So, basically, Service is publishing data to SNS Topic which gets subscribed by AWS Lambda Function. Then, this AWS Lambda Function pushes the data to Dynamo Db. Now, I am adding a DLQ with AWS Lambda to store error processed messages.

Error messages can be due to an error in publisher application or consumer application. Eg. Publisher changed the format of data being published and say I am not supporting it in AWS Lambda and it gives some error.

I wanted to know after pushing to DLQ such messages, what do we normally do?

1. Do we try again to push the data by changing the AWS Lambda function? Is this step done manually or we make a job which pushes the data from DLQ to lambda function periodically?
2. We normally just put an alarm on DLQ and then manually handle this?
3. Since Sometimes, the issue can be due to Dynamo Db connection first time, which would be handled next time if we push. If we do it manually, then it would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I’m addition to Lambda DLQs, you should consider adding SNS DLQs:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/designing-durable-serverless-apps-with-dlqs-for-amazon-sns-amazon-sqs-aws-lambda/

Comment: Hey Otavio! Could you add a little more detail to this answer (I have no experience with aws at all so I am not sure what exactly you'd add) as this might be picked up as "link-only answer" and could be flagged for deletion. The idea is that an answer might turn useless in case the link goes down. Would appreciate the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I can comment here for SQS -> DLQ
Don't need to move the message because it will come with so many other challenges like duplicate messages, recovery scenarios, lost message, de-duplication check and etc.

**Here is the solution which we implemented -**

Usually, we use the DLQ for transient errors, not for permanent errors. So took below approach -

1. Read the message from DLQ like a regular queue

   **Benefits**

   - To avoid duplicate message processing
   - Better control on DLQ- Like I put a check, to process only when the regular queue is completely processed.
   - Scale up the process based on the message on DLQ
2. Then follow the same code which regular queue is following.
3. More reliable in case of aborting the job or  the process got terminated while processing (e.g. Instance killed or process terminated)

   **Benefits**

   - Code reusability
   - Error handling
   - Recovery and message replay
4. Extend the message visibility so that no other thread process them.

   **Benefit**

   - Avoid processing same record by multiple threads.
5. Delete the message only when either there is a permanent error or successful.

   **Benefit**

   - Keep processing until we are getting a transient error.

Answer (score -1):

AWS Lambda Dead Letter Queues directs events that cannot be processed to the Amazon SNS topic or Amazon SQS queue that you’ve configured for the Lambda function.

So handling the error with given payload, using a service subscribed to the SNS topic or reading messages from SQS is up to the developer to decide. Addressing the questions listed,

1. You can use another Lambda function subscribed to a SNS topic to process the message.
2. Yes, its more similar to setup alarm and manually handle it.
3. By default, a failed Lambda function invoked asynchronously is retried twice, and then the event is discarded unless there is a DLQ setup. So if its a dynamodb connection problem, probably solved in the second invocation.